# How to set window text by its handle in another process?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ipc, messaging

For my purposes I need to set text for a window that belongs to another process using its `HWND` handle. I came up with the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
BOOL SetWindowTextInAnotherProcess(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR pStrText)
{
    //Set text of the 'hWnd' (assuming that 'hWnd' is in another process)
    //'pStrText' = ASCIIZ string to set
    //RETURN:
    //      = TRUE if done
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    if(hWnd &&
        pStrText)
    {
        DWORD dwProcID = 0;
        ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcID);
        if(dwProcID)
        {
            HANDLE hProc = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, dwProcID);
            if(hProc)
            {
                int nLn = lstrlen(pStrText);

                int ncbSzStr = (nLn + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
                VOID* pVMem = ::VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, ncbSzStr, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
                if(pVMem)
                {
                    SIZE_T sztWrtn = 0;
                    if(::WriteProcessMemory(hProc, pVMem, pStrText, ncbSzStr, &sztWrtn))
                    {
                        if(sztWrtn == ncbSzStr)
                        {
                            DWORD_PTR dwMsgRes = 0xCCCCABAB;
                            if(::SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)pVMem,
                                SMTO_NORMAL | SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG | SMTO_ERRORONEXIT,
                                1000 * 2,
                                &dwMsgRes))
                            {
                                //Check result
                                if(dwMsgRes != 0xCCCCABAB &&
                                    dwMsgRes == TRUE)
                                {
                                    //Done
                                    bRes = TRUE;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Free mem
                    ::VirtualFreeEx(hProc, pVMem, ncbSzStr, MEM_DECOMMIT);
                }

                ::CloseHandle(hProc);
            }
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}
```

`SendMessageTimeout` returns `FALSE` and `GetLastError` returns 0.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

PS. Both processes are running non-elevated on the same desktop.

Comment: Standard window messages marshal their parameters across process boundaries. In trying to marshal parameters manually you wind up passing an invalid pointer.

Comment: @IInspectable: So you mean I'd be OK doing just `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)pStrText);`?

Comment: That's what the documentation for [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) says: *"The system only does marshalling for system messages (those in the range 0 to (**WM_USER**-1)). To send other messages (those >= **WM_USER**) to another process, you must do custom marshalling."* `WM_SETTEXT` has numeric value 0xC and falls into the range of messages that are marshaled by the system.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK. That was an overkill :)

Comment: Still, if I was dispatching a message above `WM_USER` with a pointer in parameter, that's how I would marshal it, correct?

Comment: Your implementation is one way to perform custom marshaling. A file mapping object with a remote thread in the target process is another option. You could also use a DLL with a shared data segment.